# Angular: Change boolean value on click

Tags: angular, typescript

So, I have a toggle button and a function. I want that when I click on my button, my boolean value goes from `TRUE` to `FALSE` and from `FALSE` to `TRUE`. And then this value is send to my function.

Below you can find the html and ts:

```
 <mat-slide-toggle id='stop-camera' (change)='stopCamera($event)'></mat-slide-toggle>
```

.

```
  public stopCamera($event: boolean) : void{
    let num : 0;
    $event =! $event;
    if($event===true){
      console.log('Hi ' +num);
    }else{
      console.log('False');
    }
  }
```

The problem here is that my console only returns me falses...

I know it's something really basic and even simple, but because it's so simple and basic I can't find out how to do it... So I would like to get some help please .
I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me.

P.S: I'm on Angular 9 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.component.html

```
 <mat-slide-toggle id='stop-camera' (change)='stopCamera($event)'></mat-slide-toggle>
```

2.Mat-Slide toggle will give you the events when toggle changes no need to put ! condition

```
public stopCamera(event:any) : void{
    let num : 0;
    if(event.checked){
      console.log('Hi' +num);
    }else{
      console.log('False');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to define a variable/state that will update on button click

toggleState = true

(click) = 'toggleState()'

```
public toggleState(){
  this.toggleState = !this.toggleState
}
```

You can access the variable in any function you want in your component.

Comment: No use to take extra function  can use the (change) event only

Comment: he asked the state change on click, not on change

Answer (score -1):

One possible way is to use two-way data binding with [`NgModel`](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#displaying-and-updating-properties-with-ngmodel). Your template:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="checked" (ngModelChange)="toggle()">
  Toggle
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Your component:

```
checked = true;

toggle(): void {
  console.log(this.checked);
  // do more stuff
}
```